# Compiler error while compiling user defined class

Tags: c++, string, class, pointers, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile this program I created but I keep receiving compiler errors and I don't understand how to fix them.

I created a Class called MyClass; it has private members and public members.

Private Members:

- variable of type int named num.
- Another variable of type string named description.

Public Members (Member functions):

1. Default Constructor: I Initialized num and description to 0 (Zero) with an empty string.
2. Constructor:  Two input parameters (int and string types) and
                   Initialize num and description using the parameters.
3. GetNum   : No parameter, return the value of num member variable.
4. SetNum   : 1 parameter of type int;
                   set the value of num member variable equal to 
                   the value of the parameter.
5. GetDesc  : No parameter; return the value of description 
                   member variable.
6. SetDesc  : 1 parameter of type string; 
                  set the value of description member variable equal to 
                   the value of the parameter.
7. Square   : No parameter;
                 return the square of the num member variable.
8. SquareRoot   : No parameter;
    if num > 0, return (integer portion only) of the square 
                 root of the num member variable; otherwise return 0.
9. Factorial    : No parameter;
                 if num > 0, return the factorial of the num member
                 variable; otherwise return 1.
10. IsNegative  : No parameter;
                  return true(boolean) if the num member variable is < 0;
                  return false(boolean) if the num member variable is >=0.

That's what I am trying to do and below is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
private:
int num = 0;
std::string description = 0;

public:
MyClass();

MyClass(int n1, std::string const& n) : num(n1), description(n){}
int GetNum();
int SetNum(int* Pointer);
string GetDesc();
char SetDesc(char* Pointer2);
int Square();
double SquareRoot();
int Factorial();
bool IsNegative();
};

MyClass::MyClass(){
//nothing
}

int GetNum()
{
int num;
return num;
}
void SetNum(int* Pointer)
{
int num;
*Pointer = num;
}
string GetDesc()
{
string description;
return description;
}
void SetDesc(string* Pointer2)
{
string description;
*Pointer2 = description;
}
int Square()
{
int num;
return(num * num);
}
int SquareRoot()
{
int num; 
if (num > 0)
{
return sqrt(num);
}
else
{
return 0;
}
}
int Factorial()

{
int num;
if (num > 0 )
{
for (int a = 1; a<=num; a++)
{
num = num * a;
return num;
}
}
else 
return 0;
}
bool IsNegative()
{
int num;
if (num < 0)
{
return true;
}
if (num >= 0)
{
return false;
}
else
{
return 0;
}
}
bool IsNegative()
{
int num;
if (num < 0)
{
return true;
}
if (num >= 0)
{
return false;
}
else
{
return 0;
}

void Display(MyClass b)
{
cout << b.GetNum() << endl;
cout << b.GetDesc() << endl;
cout << b.Square() << endl;
cout << b.SquareRoot() << endl;
cout << b.Factorial() << endl;
cout << b.IsNegative() << endl;
}

int main () 
{ 
bool flag = false;
char str1[100], str2[100];

cin >> str1 >> str2;
for (int i=0; i < strlen(str1); i++)
{
if (i==0 && str1[i] == '-')
continue;
if (!isdigit(str1[i]))
{
flag = true;
break;
}
}

if (!flag)
{
MyClass b(atoi(str1),str2); 
Display(b);
}
else
{
MyClass b; 
Display(b);

}

return 0;
}
```

The New Compiler Error is:
Here is the error:    warning: control reaches end of non-void function 
   }
   ^
/tmp/ccIwu0FB.o: In function `Display(MyClass)':
myclass.cc:(.text+0x1be): undefined reference to`MyClass::GetNum()'
myclass.cc:(.text+0x1f0): undefined reference to `MyClass::GetDesc()'
myclass.cc:(.text+0x22c): undefined reference to`MyClass::Square()'
myclass.cc:(.text+0x257): undefined reference to `MyClass::SquareRoot()'
myclass.cc:(.text+0x282): undefined reference to`MyClass::Factorial()'
myclass.cc:(.text+0x2ad): undefined reference to `MyClass::IsNegative()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon, but it is more urgent that you read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  Line numbers in the hundreds are an indication that you have not made your code minimal.  Please also indent your code — what you've presented is largely unreadable because there is no indentation and erratic spacing between functions.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1st error

The value returned by `strlen()` is of type `size_t`, which is unsigned.  Your compiler is set to complain about comparisons involving signed and unsigned values, so you need to fix things so that you have either two signed or two unsigned values.

In the context, the simplest/best fix is to change:

```
for (int i=0; i < strlen(str1); i++)
```

into:

```
for (size_t i = 0, len = strlen(str1); i < len; i++)
```

This fixes the type conversion issue and also avoids evaluating `strlen()` in the loop condition (when you have `strlen()` in the loop condition, it converts a linear algorithm into a quadratic algorithm).

#### 2nd error

You have the constructor:

```
MyClass(std::string const& n, int num) : description(n){}
```

You try to invoke:

```
MyClass b(atoi(str1),str2);
```

This has the `int` and `string` arguments back to front.  Since the constructor ignores the `num` argument, it is not clear what's best to do.

Maybe:

```
MyClass(std::string const& n) : description(n){}
```

and then either

```
MyClass b(str1);
```

or:

```
MyClass b(str2);
```

(Both are syntactically valid — it is far from clear without a lot more study which, if either, is semantically correct for your program.)

Alternatively, given the description of the non-default constructor, you need:

```
MyClass(std::string const& n1, int n2) : num(n2), description(n1) {}
```

and the call should be:

```
MyClass b(str1, atoi(str2));
```

or perhaps:

```
MyClass b(str2, atoi(str1));
```

or possibly one of:

```
MyClass b(str2, atoi(str2));
MyClass b(str1, atoi(str1));
```

Comment: Thank you, I have edited my program above to comply with your advice, however I am receiving two more different compiler errors. I don't know how to adjust my program.

Comment: Here is the error:    warning: control reaches end of non-void function 
   }
   ^
/tmp/ccIwu0FB.o: In function `Display(MyClass)':
myclass.cc:(.text+0x1be): undefined reference to `MyClass::GetNum()'
myclass.cc:(.text+0x1f0): undefined reference to `MyClass::GetDesc()'
myclass.cc:(.text+0x22c): undefined reference to `MyClass::Square()'
myclass.cc:(.text+0x257): undefined reference to `MyClass::SquareRoot()'
myclass.cc:(.text+0x282): undefined reference to `MyClass::Factorial()'
myclass.cc:(.text+0x2ad): undefined reference to `MyClass::IsNegative()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status